# Node + Mongoose - getting attributes from Model's Schema via findById

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm looking to extract `User` email via his id, with `findById()`, without making another call.

- Route method is irrelevant at this point.

`router.delete('/:userId', (req,res,next) =>{
        console.log(User.findById(req.params.userId).Schema.email);
    })`

The code above is not working, yet just wanted to put it up to show what i'm trying to extract.

Instead of parsing the User object, does mongoose have a method to extract model attributes via `findById()` without an async call ? it only makes sense since:

`console.log(User.findById(req.params.userId));` does return the whole Mongoose object / Model.

Would be happy to get your thoughts.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want to accomplish,  The mongoose query calls are all asynchronous.

Comment: No you cannot achieve it without an async call.